# How does one force PyCharm to open a file as XML?

Tags: xml, qt, pyqt4, qt-designer, pycharm

I have some .ui files generated by Qt Designer; they are simple XML files but PyCharm refuses to open them. The filetype is listed among the ones "recognized" by PyCharm, but I can't find a way to specify how it should deal with it.

Does anybody know how can I force PyCharm to let me edit the XML source?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can edit associations in `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `File Types`, map `.ui` extension to `XML files` type.

Comment: D'oh, for some reason I didn't think I could do that, but actually I can -- thanks.